# AWS Instance different IP Address

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-scraping

I am new to AWS (and even servers) so please ignore if this sounds a pretty obvious thing to you.

I created a new AWS instance and for that I got this IP address: 54.86.121.145 but when I run  ip addr show, I get another IP address.

```
 bitnami@ip-172-31-4-116:~$ wget http://icanhazip.com -qO-
 54.86.121.145 
 bitnami@ip-172-31-4-116:~/anant$ ip addr show
 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group       default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:be:6a:f0:42:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.31.4.116/20 brd 172.31.15.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::8be:6aff:fef0:42b5/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The problem I am facing is that I am writing a scrapping tool (in Java) that works fine in my local laptop (Windows) and my friend's laptop (Linux) but I try to run from AWS I get 403 error.

1) What is the outgoing IP address when I connect through my Java program?

2) Is it possible to get a floating IP address (that are not in blacklisted categories).

3) Is there any workaround to get that scrapping tool working in my AWS Instance? I am ready to move to another server (outside AWS) if you suggested that is not possibly blacklisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the IP from within your ec2 instance.

1. Use cURL to get metadata of the instance and hence your IP

   **Local**

   ```
   curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
   ```

   **Public**

   ```
   curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
   ```

   Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html
2. Using AWS CLI:

   ```
   aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instanceId --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress'
   ```

   Replace `PublicIpAddress` with `PrivateIpAddress` to get the desired one.

   Reference: https://alestic.com/2013/11/aws-cli-query/
3. Since you're using Java, you could leverage [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) to get the IP if you fetch the instance Id after creating instance:

   ```
   DescribeInstancesRequest describeRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
   DescribeInstancesResult describeResult = ec2.describeInstances(describeRequest);
   Instance instance = describeResult.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0);
   String publicIp = instance.getPublicIpAddress();
   String privateIp = instance.getPrivateIpAddress();
   ```

   where `ec2` is an `AmazonEC2Client` with proper credentials **and** region.